# Waffles or pancakes?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, test

I'm a software engineer and in one of my interviews they asked me this question :

> Do you prefer waffles or pancakes?

I don't know whether they asked this question to reduce my stress level, or to probe my line of thinking. I tried to search, but to no avail, so I decided to ask it here. This question is interesting for me because I find that some other companies asked this question for product manager roles, or front-end developers, and my answer is 'waffles'.

<sub>PS. If this is not the right place of my question please let me know , I remove or move my question into another stack.</sub>

Comment: Must be a reference to the waffles meme.

Comment: Probably it's so they seem relatable and therefore makes you less stressed. waffles for me

Comment: After researching this question-I have a theory. The theory is that people who prefer pancakes are more “basic needs” kind of people, while people who prefer waffles are more adventurous and willing to take risks. Those who are into French toast are high maintenance. Just an idea. :)

Answer (score 1):

This question might be borderline ontopic here, as it would fare better at Workplace.SE or similar sites. However, being involved in job interviews on a regular basis (in science) I became intrigued nonetheless. Whether it's applicable I can't tell, because I don't know in what area (of research?) you exactly applied for a job, but I found a *possible* answer on [this blog site](https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/funny-weird-interview-questions), and I quote (bolding and italicization mine):

> ***"What do you think of garden gnomes?"***
> This question, asked by Trader Joe's, is a ridiculous and silly
> question. More than anything else, it's **intended to loosen the
> candidate up, see a glimpse of their personality, and gain insight
> into culture fit**.
>
> There's **no right answer to this question**, but if your team likes to be
> sarcastic with one another, you might want a candidate to say, "If I
> could get a job as one then I probably wouldn't be here today talking
> to you."
>
> Ultimately, if your candidate is **able to handle** this curveball with
> ease, it shows an impressive **ability to react quickly** to bizarre
> circumstances.